# Android Auth Error: "GetToken failed with status code: INVALID_AUDIENCE"

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, google-signin

There are a couple of questions about this vague error code already, but none have solved this issue for me, so I'll try again. First, here is the boilerplate code for signing in.

```
      GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestServerAuthCode("web app client ID copied from Dev API Console", false)
        .build();


  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth
        .GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
  startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

With this code, I get a dialog and can select the appropriate user account. Yay! However, I then get a canceled code in onActivityResult, so I check logcat and notice the error message in the title. Then I search for other people with this issue, but haven't been able to figure out what the issue is in my case.

So let's check off common issues from other posts.

- The Firebase console shows my app is registered with the correct SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints
- Both release and debug builds use the same keystore
- In the Google API manager, my "OAuth consent screen" is configured
- I've also verified the domain of the authorized redirect URIs
- I've re-downloaded the Firebase GoogleServices.json file, just to be sure
- There are no package name issues. In fact, Firebase Analytics has been running just fine on this app in the wild
- In the Play Store dev console, my OAuth client shows up in "Settings->API access"
- My Firebase project is linked in the Play Store dev console "Linked Accounts" settings section
- I've waited 10 hours, just to see if Google's backend would take time to set this up

For searchability, right after the logcat error message in the title, I get the following logcat print.

> You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed
>   error: INVALID_AUDIENCE

Comment: Which version of firebase are you using in your app?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes, I'm using firebase/play-services version 10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Web Client ID has to be generated in the same user account as Firebase, not your Play Store account. In my case, the two accounts are separate, and Google throws this error instead of linking the information properly. My Firebase account is linked to my Play Store account but that apparently doesn't mean the web client ID will be shared. I tried some other solutions such as linking the API Manager accounts, and that didn't work either. You must create the Web Client ID inside the same project Firebase uses in the API Manager account that is the same as your Firebase account.

Comment: How to create website client id in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your client_id, for google auth process.Delete the file from current project.Then add a new instance. This time paying careful attention to the id. use android-studio to generate the settings for firebase.
You have to have a project with multiple client ids
One is for your android app, with the SHA. Safest bet is delete your current project in the google console.Then re-create it.Then in android studio go tools= > firebase then choose the settings you want to integrate. I do not recommend manual addition.

Comment: how are you initializing your auth instance exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using Tools => Firebase. Unfortunately, this only re-downloaded the same JSON file resulting in no change. As stated, this is a live Firebase project. I most certainly will not be deleting this project and re-adding it. Millions of customers would then have a broken app.

Answer (score 0):

**Implement to your activity**

```
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

**Setup these private variables**

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
```

**Configure Google Sign In**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(SignInActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

**Initialize FirebaseAuth**

```
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
    } else {
        // Already signed in, launch the Home activity
        //You can use mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName() / getUid() / getEmail() /getPhotoUrl()

    }
```

**Sign In Method**

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("Data",data.getExtras().toString());
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.e("Result","status "+result.getStatus()+"Success"+result.isSuccess()+" "+result.getSignInAccount());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**firebaseAuthWithGoogle**

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication Successful.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**onConnectionFailed()**

```
 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Sign Out Method**

```
private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).
                setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    }
                });
        mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
}
```

Keep logs at everypoint .
if you followed all the points properly combining with the list you made it should work.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. However, I'm already doing all of this. As stated, I get an error in onActivityResult. If you are curious, here is what your log prints. Result: status Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}Successfalse null